# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'IArrowState'.ts(2322) in a Reducer function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, reduce, use-reducer

I have the following code to define a React Reducer function:

```
import { useReducer, Reducer } from 'react';
interface IArrowState {
  ascending: [
    { time: boolean },
    { user: boolean }
  ]
}

type ArrowAction = {
  type: string;
}

const Events: FC<IEventComponent> & {getLayout: (params: any) => void;} = () => {
  const arrowInitialState: IArrowState = {
    ascending: [
      { time: true },
      { user: true }
    ]
  }

  const arrowReducer: Reducer<IArrowState, ArrowAction> = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'time':
        return state.ascending['time'] = !state.ascending['time'];
      case 'user':
        return state.ascending['user'] = !state.ascending['user'];
    }
  }
}
```

However I'm getting TS2322 Type A is not assignable to type B error on line
`const arrowReducer: Reducer<IArrowState, ArrowAction>`:

[image]

Can someone explain what is going wrong here? Should I give a return type to `Reducer<IArrowState, ArrowAction>`?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Where does the `Reducer` type come from?

Comment: @LinDu added the import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't update the state correctly, you must do the immutable update for the state in the reducer function. See [immutable-update-patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

```js
import type { Reducer } from 'react';

interface IArrowState {
    ascending: [
        { time: boolean },
        { user: boolean }
    ]
}

type ArrowAction = {
    type: string;
}

const arrowInitialState: IArrowState = {
    ascending: [
        { time: true },
        { user: true }
    ]
}

const arrowReducer: Reducer<IArrowState, ArrowAction> = (state, action): IArrowState => {
    const [time, user] = state.ascending;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'time':
            return {
                ...state,
                ascending: [{ time: !time.time }, user]
            }
        case 'user':
            return {
                ...state,
                ascending: [time, { user: !user.user }]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const nextArrowState = arrowReducer(arrowInitialState, { type: 'time' });
console.log('nextArrowState: ', nextArrowState);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nASigJgVwGMUo4BfOAMyghDgHIoUBDQmegbgCgvgA7GCUqs0ASQCCUGgHcAyjGaCMXOKrjMAzsT65+AcwBccANoq15zDFAojAIwgQANiz7kANGfOrM+DSTsOzsyuZJ5wALpcoVxIqHCSMuJswBCuALzK5rE2cBowUPrc0YSpeepSENKifMBWzI7yijkSFXIKShnoYZraunyGJmEWCNZG+fhoZB5eaj5+UGNQE+RhkcWl8MytOATEC9h4RCQAPC0yjYJu8a1JVqkAfHAZABR5TVesd3wAlEZnlRc0GlHl1zCU+GVjFYQCgrr4SOEnrl2igAHQ9FA6QphDTSWqEAAWcGenxSfFR2W+mRmcEImjQ9GhKHoBiGNKYMHwUFcoJpfNRArelzZfNUGKx-SMxksozgAEImRTrO44PCoJFRWpQny6X4GGqWSKvByuTyjfzBSjppqvOK+gModYrnN-PK1ai1eQNTbtTTcChhPhHDBWTa4CbucimtxzKF1hD4HwUAAPGAJAEopFbGQ7I5QEmtaq1YD1QHOhDIHKM6z0cjfbjgjRONGOCB6Z70JOp9NtJpGehXLtp1qA+tcIA)(Click "Run" to check the logs in right panel)